# Migrating to GIT from SVN

Tags: svn, git, git-svn

Right now we are using **SVN** for our subversion control. And we are pretty happy with it. We use it for following case

- Project Sharing and merging the code.

Now we also want to use the following case

- There is a folder say "plugin" which is needed to include in many project as a subfolder , now when we change something in "plugin" and commit it. The changes should affect in the subfolder of all project having it (atleast it should show incoming changes for the plugin folder in projects).

---

**I have following queries:**

1. Can we do the second case in subversion. If yes, how??
2. Is git better for both the cases, if yes, then how to start with git and achive the two cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Git has something called [submodules](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule) which does what svn externals do.

Since you mention merging, Git is very good at handling merging and branching and is one of the strong reasons to start using Git over SVN. Moreover Git is a distributed version control system with added benefits of local commits, branches, merging etc and developers can easily push and pull changes amongst themselves without need for a central server /repo

So if project sharing and merging are what you are looking for, Git is the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

The second use case can be achieved in Subversion using [externals](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch07s03.html). In your projects, create empty plugin folders with externals definitions to a separate plugin repository. When you checkout or update a project, it will resolve the externals definition and update/checkout the plugin repository.

Comment: thanks, one more thing what if the files of that plugin directory is scattered in the project repository will it work???

Comment: No. You need to split them out in separate folders.